# Either PoinerReleased or Command not firing in custom control

Tags: uwp, custom-controls, uwp-xaml

I have created a custom button, inherited from the ButtonBase class. I have added storyboards for all events like PointerPressed,  PointerReleased, PointerEntered & PointerExited. It works fine until I added the Command & CommandParameter properties to my custom button in the calling project. I find these properties in my custom button control, since it is inherited from ButtonBase classes.

But If I add e.Handled = true; in PointerPressed event, the command property works, but the storyboard for PointerReleased not fires. 
If I remove the e.Handled = true; in PointerPressed event, the command property not works, but the storyboard for PointerReleased works as expected and programmed. 
For simplicity I have omitted the .cs file code. It is nothing but the events that call the corresponding storyboards. How to solve this?

```
<ButtonBase
x:Class="CustomButtonWithMvvmCommand.Views.Usercontrols.BtnCust2.ButtonCust2"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:CustomButtonWithMvvmCommand.Views.Usercontrols.BtnCust2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400"
IsEnabled="True"
IsTapEnabled="True"
IsTabStop="True"   
IsRightTapEnabled="False"
SizeChanged="GrdBase_OnSizeChanged">

<ButtonBase.Resources>

        <Storyboard x:Name="StoryPointerEntered3" AutoReverse="False">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.10" Storyboard.TargetName="GrdBase" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" To="0.92"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.10" Storyboard.TargetName="GrdBase" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" To="0.97"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.10" Storyboard.TargetName="GrdBase" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" To="0"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.10" Storyboard.TargetName="GrdBase" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" To="0"/>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Name="StoryPointerExited3" AutoReverse="False">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.10" Storyboard.TargetName="GrdBase" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" To="1"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.10" Storyboard.TargetName="GrdBase" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" To="1"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.10" Storyboard.TargetName="GrdBase" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" To="0"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.10" Storyboard.TargetName="GrdBase" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" To="0"/>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Name="StoryPointerDown3" AutoReverse="False">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.05" Storyboard.TargetName="GrdBase" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" To="0.82"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.05" Storyboard.TargetName="GrdBase" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" To="0.9"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.05" Storyboard.TargetName="GrdBase" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" To="0"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.05" Storyboard.TargetName="GrdBase" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" To="0"/>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Name="StoryPointerUp3" AutoReverse="False">

        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.05" Storyboard.TargetName="GrdBase" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" To="1.0"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.05" Storyboard.TargetName="GrdBase" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" To="1.0"/>

        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.05" Storyboard.TargetName="GrdBase" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" To="0"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.05" Storyboard.TargetName="GrdBase" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" To="0"/>


        </Storyboard>

    </ButtonBase.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="GrdBase" 
    Tapped="GrdBase_OnTapped"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    IsTapEnabled="True"                      
    PointerPressed="ButtonBase_PointerPressed"
    PointerReleased="ButtonBase_PointerReleased"
    PointerCanceled="GrdBase_PointerCanceled"
    PointerCaptureLost="GrdBase_PointerCaptureLost"
    PointerEntered="ImgBack_OnPointerEntered"
    PointerExited="ImgBack_OnPointerExited"
    Background="Transparent">

        <Grid>
        <!--some controls-->
        </Grid>

        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
    </Grid>
</ButtonBase>
```

Comment: Could you share a simple project for us? I could reproduce your issue with above code.

Comment: @ Nico Zhu - MSFT, here is the project. https://github.com/sunsewingmachine/CustomButtonCommand

Comment: Good, I will test your demo.